# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList Redirect to Eidt View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET MVC, please excuse me if my question is too simple.

I need to create a drop down list that will list employee last and first name. When the user selects an employee from the drop down list, my site should redirect the user to the Edit view that will allow the user to edit the record.

My code in the Controller is like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    ViewBag.NameList = (from e in db.Employee select e.FirstName + "," + e.LastName);
    return View(employee.ToList());
}
```

And my View is like this:

```
<p>
    Fast way: @Html.DropDownList("Edit",  new SelectList(ViewBag.NameList))
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new SelectList(ViewBag.NameList));
</p>
```

This in my model:

```
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

The above code does not work as I expected. The page cannot be redirected. Maybe I still need to bind the ID of the item in the DropDownList? Please can someone help me implement this feature?

Comment: Hi @Wen. If u need to redirect without button click, you will need to insert javascript. With button click will be so much easier. Which method do you prefer?

Comment: Hi @YatFeiLeong thanks for your comment. I prefer add a button click. But if you can, can you introduce both methods? If not, just introduce the method of clicking the button. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day Wen

First of all you have a Action Result that list the Employee that goes like

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.Emp = new SelectList(( from s in db.Employee.OrderBy(a =>a.Forename)
                                           select new {Id = s.EmployeeID, Name = 
s.Forename +  " - " + s.Surname }),
                                           "Id","Name");

        return View();
    }
```

Then your view will be like this

```
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Employees",FormMethod.Get))
{

@Html.Label("Employee")
@Html.DropDownList("id",(SelectList)ViewBag.Emp)  
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}
```

From the view, you can see I have amended the 'Html.BeginFrom' to direct to Employess/Edit so it will redirect it to ActionResult of Edit Employee. Also you see the dropdown list is named as 'id' which is the parameter of the Edit Action Result Parameter.

This is the Edit ActionResult in Controller

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Employee employee = db.Employee.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
```

It is that simple!

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help! If so, can you introduce another method? It's the kind of method that doesn't require buttons.

Comment: Same quote but create a javascript that invoke during the value change of the drop down list. Can do this method for education purpose, it is surely not fit for commercial use. Write u the code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample code that redirect to edit view when use select from the dropdownlist.
As mention you only need to change the view. Create a Javascript function that submit this form and then call the function while dropdownlist change.

Here is the code. Do vote this as answer if it addresses your concern

```
@model IEnumerable<Incendo.Entities.Employee>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employees", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "TransPost" }))
{

@Html.Label("Employee")
@Html.DropDownList("id", (SelectList)ViewBag.Emp, " ", new {@onchange = "postTrans()" 
})
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}


@section scripts{
<script>
    function postTrans() {
        
        document.getElementById("TransPost").submit();
    }
</script>



}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried two methods and they are both good. Thank you for letting me learn new knowledge.

Comment: Please vote it as answer if it works for you

Comment: I will, but I am new to stackflow. Therefore I don't have enough reputation. I can only mark that the answer has been accepted. But I will come back to vote your answer when I have enough reputation. Thanks again for your help.